# Return CreatedAtRoute location from ODataController

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, odatacontroller

I have ODataController with a Post method in it which should return a URL to a newly created OData resource, something like the following:

```
public class TasksController: ODataController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Request request)
    {
        ...
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetTask", new Dictionary<string, object>{{"id", id}}, new object());
    }

    [ODataRoute(RouteName = "GetTask")]
    public IActionResult Get(int key)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my case I'm getting "InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values" when returning CreatedAtRoute. I can fix the issue by changing code to:

```
return Created($"{baseUri}/odata/Task({id})", new object());
```

Is there any way to use CreatedAtRoute instead and making it return correct OData path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem also. I was able to get it working by adding "odataPath" to the `routeValues`:

```cs
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id, odataPath = $"{baseUri}/odata/Task({id})" }, new object());
```

**UPDATE:**

I did find an alternate/better approach. When inheriting from `ODataController`, you have access to two additional result types: `CreatedODataResult<TEntity>` and `UpdatedODataResult<TEntity>`. So this works:

```cs
return Created(new object());
```

That returns a 201 with the OData-specific create route in the location header.

Answer (score 0):

The route your are returning in the Created method: `"{baseUri}/odata/Task({id})"` doesn't exist. The simplest fix would be to change your URL to match your controller method.

Change: `$"{baseUri}/odata/Task({id})"`

to match `$"{baseUri}/odata/GetTask({id})"`